# undo button in Drawing App with UIKit

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios6

I wam trying to implement undo button , everything is working fine and i am able to cache the action but somehow previously drawn lines are still there , they should disappear on every undoclick action Please help

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    path = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
    mouseSwiped = NO;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    lastPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    CGPoint p = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    [path moveToPoint:p];
    [pathArray addObject:path];
   // NSLog(@"%@",pathArray);
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {


    mouseSwiped = YES;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    CGPoint p = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    [path addLineToPoint:p];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
    [self.tempDrawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), brush );
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), red, green, blue, 1.0);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),kCGBlendModeNormal);

    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    self.tempDrawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    [self.tempDrawImage setAlpha:opacity];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    lastPoint = currentPoint;
   [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint p = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    [path addLineToPoint:p];

    if(!mouseSwiped) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
        [self.tempDrawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
        CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), brush);
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), red, green, blue, opacity);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
        CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        CGContextFlush(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        self.tempDrawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.mainImage.frame.size);
    [self.mainImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];
    [self.tempDrawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:opacity];
    self.mainImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    self.tempDrawImage.image = nil;
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    [self mainImage];
    [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
     [path removeAllPoints];
}
```

with following undo function and patharray count is  decrementing at every click but draw lines are still there

```
-(IBAction)undoButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    NSLog(@"pathArray count is %i", [pathArray count]);
    if([pathArray count]>0){
        UIBezierPath *_path=[pathArray lastObject];
        [bufferArray addObject:_path];
        [pathArray removeLastObject];
        //self.tempDrawImage.image;
        [self.view  setNeedsDisplay];
    }
}
```

Comment: Please help i just need to remove the previously drawn lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using the `tempImage` ivar to accumulate the strokes of the drawing, but when you click undo you don't do anything to erase the lines that have already been drawn there. I don't know how complex your drawing requirements are. If they're simple, you could just iterate over `pathArray` in the `-drawRect` of the view calling `-stroke` on each path (you'd need to set lineWidth etc on the path or in the view each time you draw a stroke, of course). As a simple optimization you could calculate the bounds of new/deleted strokes and then call `setNeedsDisplayInRect:` on the appropriate portion of the view.  As it is you're updating `tempImage` every time the touch moves, which I imagine has quite a high overhead.

Comment: i am following this link http://www.raywenderlich.com/18840/how-to-make-a-simple-drawing-app-with-uikit , any help with  code ?